# How to load an external library and have it useable in Local Development

Tags: lightning-web-components, libraries, lwc-local-development

So I have loki loaded on it's static resource like a good boy and whenever I run the component in an actual org everything is hunky dory however testing in local dev always makes it return a 404 for the static resource even if the static resource is in my project.

> GET http://localhost:3333/assets/project/7cc83a2fcb/staticresources/lokijs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

here is my abbreviated code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import lokijs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/lokijs';

connectedCallback() {

    //log loading started
    console.log('loading started');

    loadScript(this, lokijs)
        .then(() => {
            //log library loaded
            console.log('LokiJS library loaded successfully');

            //create database
            let dataBase = new loki();
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error('Error loading LokiJS library: ', e);
        });
}
```

As stated works perfectly in a real org, but not locally is the expected behaviour of the local runner?

EDIT: progress has been made if I add .js to the loadscript it works locally.

```
loadScript(this, lokijs+'.js')
```

However this causes it to fail on the org until I change it back to

```
loadScript(this, lokijs)
```

This is fine for testing for now I just need to remember to remove/add js dependent on destination, but I shouldn't need to.

Comment: Post your EDIT part as answer. It solved the issue for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably seen this already but the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/lwc-localdev-supported-modules) does list as supported:

> @salesforce/resourceUrl
> Exposes static resources in your Salesforce org. Static resources are copied and served from the DX project location on your filesystem, force-app/main/default/staticresources, to the server.

I suggest that you open your browser's Developer Tools and observe the Network tab when the error occurs to see if anything is revealed there. And also check the Console tab.

Comment: Was fiddling around, and it seems there is a discrepancy between how the org and local testing loads resources I have updated the initial question. I have checked my local version of SFDX, and I am up to date, so I assume this is a bug.

Comment: Hi @Tythus, +1 from me on your question for the `.js` work around. Pretty annoying. Suggest you post that as the answer here and you'll be able to accept it in a couple of days.